# Sumar columnas de una tabla mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, mvc

tengo una tabla creada de esta manera

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sale.Date)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sale.Warehouse.Name)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sale.Date)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sale.Warehouse.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="center">
                            <strong>Totals</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <strong>Total Price</strong>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            <strong>Total Quantity</strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Necesitaría sumar las dos ultimas columnas y agregar los totales en Total Price y Total Quantity respectivamente.
Mi pregunta es como hacerlo mediante javascript, desde el controlador o desde el modelo?
Este es mi modelo:

```
public class SaleDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int SaleDetailId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorFieldRequired")]
    public int SaleId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorFieldRequired")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorFieldRequired")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorStringMaxMin", MinimumLength = 1)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Strings), Name = "Product")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorFieldRequired")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorDecimal")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Strings), Name = "Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorFieldRequired")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Strings), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ErrorDecimal")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Strings), Name = "Quantity")]
    public double Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual Sale Sale { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Y este el controlador:

```
public ActionResult DateSales(string value)
    {
            var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            var view = db.SaleDetails.Include(s => s.Sale).Where(s => s.Sale.Warehouse.CompanyId == user.CompanyId && s.Sale.Date == DateTime.Today);
            return View(view.ToList());
    }
```

Gracias.

Comment: puedes declarar dos variables fuera de tu foreach y cada  elemento sumas ej: QuantityTot = QuantityTot +=item.Quantity; y alfinal ya solo pintas QuantityTot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pesar de que la respuesta de Xique es correcta en términos de que soluciona el problema, es una mala práctica poner lógica en la vista. Las vistas, en un modelo MVC, son solo para representar la información que reciben y nada más. Esta lógica debiese ir dentro del modelo que tienes, a modo de métodos helpers: `summarizeTotalDetails(list details) {...}`
 o, mejor aún, en una clase helper que se especialice en este tipo de cálculos (`SaleDetalesSummarizer`, por ejemplo). Con lo cual tu código es reutilizable por otros controladores :)

saludos

Answer (score 1):

En la vista seria declarando dos variables fuera de tu `foreach` y ya dentro vas sumando las cantidades más o meno así:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sale.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sale.Warehouse.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
        </th>
    </tr>
        var PriceTot=0.0M;
        var QuantityTot =0.0D;
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sale.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sale.Warehouse.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            </td>
        </tr>
        PriceTot+=item.Price;
        QuantityTot+=item.Quantity;
    }
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
            <strong>Totals</strong>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <strong>Total Price :@PriceTot</strong>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <strong>Total Quantity: @QuantityTot</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Otra opción seria sumarlos en tu controlador y  ya solo pasar los datos a tu vista con viewbag algo asi:

```
public ActionResult DateSales(string value)
    {
            var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            var view = db.SaleDetails.Include(s => s.Sale).Where(s => s.Sale.Warehouse.CompanyId == user.CompanyId && s.Sale.Date == DateTime.Today);
            return View(view.ToList());
            ViewBag.TotalPrice=view.Sum(m=>m.Price);
            ViewBag.TotalQuantity=view.Sum(m=>m.Quantity);
    }
```

y ya en la vista solo  pones tu ViewBag en la tabla

```
   <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">
            <strong>Totals</strong>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <strong>Total Price :@ViewBag.TotalPrice</strong>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <strong>Total Quantity: @ViewBag.TotalQuantity</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar la variables PriceTot y QuantityTot por fuera del foreach me da error no me las reconoce

Comment: @NicolasComaschi si las pones dentro se  volverán a poner en 0 cada vez que   entre a un nuevo elemento

Comment: @NicolasComaschi ya actualice con otra opción si gustas revisarla

Answer (score 0):

Me decidi por hacerlo desde el modelo. Lo que hice fue crear una clase que herede del modelo original y haga la suma ya, algo asi:

```
[NotMapped]
public class DateSaleView : SaleDetail
{
    public List<SaleDetail> Details { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public double TotalQuantity { get { return Details == null ? 0 : Details.Sum(d => d.Quantity); } }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public decimal TotalValue { get { return Details == null ? 0 : Details.Sum(d => d.Price); } }
}
```